# Mysql master slave replication in windows

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help me out for the master slave replication in Windows(Step by step).I have googled it but there is no proper configuration(my.ini) found for windows ,its always for LINUX. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you considered consulting the MySQL documentation?

Comment: What makes you think mysql behaves any differently on ms-windows?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 ) on master

stop server on master,

set server-id =1,

enable log-bin=mysql-bin in my.ini,
start mysql server

2) on slave

stop mysql server,

set server-id =2 in my.ini

start mysql server

3) on master
create replication user on master with slave IP like below

```
CREATE USER 'repli_user'@'slave_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repli_user'@'slave_IP';
```

4) Go To Master

```
flush tables with read lock;

show master status;
```

(note offset file number and offset position)

```
unlock tables;
```

5) On slave

```
change master to
master_host = 'master_IP',
master_user = 'repli_user',
master_password= 'password',
master_log_file = 'mysql-bin.<file-number>',
master_log_pos = offset-pos;
```

6) 
on slave

```
start slave;

show slave status;
```

You should get "Waiting for master to send event" as slave status;

Comment: Thanks!!......Yes @Priyanshu i did the same but when i am trying to show slave status it is showing like "Connecting to master"

Comment: check if master connected to slave.
ping master IP address. like
Ping 192.168.58.xx.
if master and slave in different domain , enable port forwarding on master to allow connection from slave.